# Calulus of variations with differential coefficient on end point

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

$J = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(y,y',x)dx$

I want to find the function $y(x)$ that satisfies $y'(x_2)=a$
and makes $J$ extrema

It can't be solved using Euler-Lagrange Equation because of the first condition.

Is there any methods for solving that problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'it can't be solved using Euler-Lagrange Equation because of the first condition'. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Solution of the Euler Lagrange Equation decided by start and end point value of the function.

Comment: And it is not satisfies y'(x_2)=a

Comment: Solving projectile (parabolic trajectory) problem would be helpful.

Comment: @SoonwonMoon, do you think that you can't use Euler-Lagrange Equation since that seems to be based on knowledge of the end points?

Comment: The question (v1) is not well-posed. For starter, at least 2 boundary conditions are needed.

Comment: @Qmechanic Do you mean that both y'(x_1) and y'(x_2) are needed?

Comment: @Narasimham formula of projectiles are uniquely decided by start point, end point and time

Comment: @md2perpe yes, euler lagrange equation gives most optimized result and it might not satisfy the condition.

Comment: If slope and  velocity (at start or end), $(y_2-y_1)  \,or\,( x_2 -x_1) $ are fixed then under action of gravity a parabolic trajectory results with minimum time,

Comment: @Narasimhan let x(t_1), x(t_2), y(t_1) and y(t_2) be fixed. then the parabola will be decided. but I want to add more condition : x'(t_1) and y'(t_1). so this is not a common situation

Comment: I still believe that the Lagrange equation can be used. The derivation of the Lagrange equation relies on assuming $y$ to be the solution and the variation to just vary in the internal of the interval.